# How tell if CSS class is recognized?

Tags: css, reactjs, firefox

I have a simple React weather app I am experimenting around with.
The "table" and "table-hover" css classes used below are bootstrap classes.

```
<table className="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Temperature (K)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

As a test, I changed as follows:

```
<table className="tableJIBERRISH table-hoverJIBBERISH">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Temperature (K)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

As expected, the formatting breaks. 
However, in my debugging tools (I am using Firefox), I don't have any indication as to whether the CSS class being used is valid or not. How can I get this feedback from my browser's devtools?

Comment: You always see in devtools if class applies some CSS rules or not.

Comment: Where exactly is this?

Comment: When you click a DOM element you'll see on the side which rules it inherits. Usually it says something like "style.css" or similar which means there's a file it's being read from. If there are no rules or just says "style agent" then you know the css isn't being loaded.

Comment: @TokyoMike In chrome and Firefox right click on an element and in the pop-up menu click inspect element. This will show you what classes are applied to an element. It also shows what styling those classes apply to the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is pretty simple. As mentioned in the comments above,

1. Open Firefox devtools
2. Right-click and select "Inspect Element"
3. On the right side of devtools under the Inspector tab, there is another group of tabs. By default, "Rules" should display all rules that are applied to the element.
4. All css classes that are applied should display here (there is a search bar to help filter as well)